# Leading Underscore transpiled wrong with es6 classes

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I am experiencing a really weird behavior and can't even say which package to blame for it.
My setup: RequireJS project with the JSXTransformer and the `jsx!` plugin
I have an es6 class like this:

```
define([
    'react'
], function(
    React
) {

    class MyComponent extends React.Component {

        myMethod() {
            otherObject.someMethod()._privateProp; // Yes, we need this accessing and have no influence on it
        }

    }

    return MyComponent;

});
```

The transpiled output in the resulting bundle after running r.js is:

```
define('jsx!project/components/InputOutput',[
    'react'
], function(
    React
) {

    var ____Class8=React.Component;for(var ____Class8____Key in ____Class8){if(____Class8.hasOwnProperty(____Class8____Key)){MyComponent[____Class8____Key]=____Class8[____Class8____Key];}}var ____SuperProtoOf____Class8=____Class8===null?null:____Class8.prototype;MyComponent.prototype=Object.create(____SuperProtoOf____Class8);MyComponent.prototype.constructor=MyComponent;MyComponent.__superConstructor__=____Class8;function MyComponent(){"use strict";if(____Class8!==null){____Class8.apply(this,arguments);}}

        MyComponent.prototype.myMethod=function() {"use strict";
            otherObject.someMethod().$MyComponent_privateProp;
        };



    return MyComponent;

});
```

Note how `otherObject.someMethod().$MyComponent_privateProp;` is written there. This obviously breaks because it is not a property on instances of MyComponent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `/** @preventMunge */` to the top of the file. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/jstransform/issues/50):

> Yes, sorry this is a non-standard fb-ism. For now you can work around this and toggle this feature off by putting `/** @preventMunge */` at the top of your file -- but that's also a pretty big fb-ism. We should (a) turn this into a transform option (rather than a direct docblock directive) and (b) make it opt-in rather than opt-out (since it's non-standard).
>
> For context: We munge all under-prefixed object properties on a per-module basis partly because our under-prefix convention applies to both objects and classes. Additionally, even if we wanted to lax the objects vs classes distinction, it's impossible to tell (in the general case) if a property is a reference to `this` since alias variables can occur (i.e. `var self = this; self._stuff;`).

Comment: That explains this, I should have added "strange" to my search query, apparently :)